# I search faker-avatar for php 8

Tags: laravel, faker, avatar

I want to use avatar in my faker users seeding and I try to use  https://github.com/ottaviano/faker-gravatar

But I got error trying to install it :

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                       
  Package ottaviano/faker-gravatar has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version:  
    - ottaviano/faker-gravatar 0.1.2 requires php ^7.1 which does not match your installed version 8.1.0.
```

Looks like it does not support php 8...
Are there similar pluging supporting php 8 ?
Or maybe I can tune this plugin to work under php 8?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this: https://github.com/LasseRafn/php-initial-avatar-generator

Answer (score 2):

You could create an issue on the repo and request that the maintainer update the package to support `PHP 8`. Alternatively you could fork the repo and either maintain that fork yourself, or create a pull request once you've updated the package.

With the above in mind though, something to note is that package is using an [abandoned faker library](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker). There is a [new fork](https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker) that is recommended for use but does not have a gravatar provider.

You could write your own provider for the newer faker library or alternatively go down the very simple route of just implementing a statement to generate a gravatar yourself.

```
'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5(strtolower(trim($faker->email()))) . '?d=identicon';
```

The above will look for an existing gravatar for the provided email address and return that if it finds one, otherwise will return a default gravatar image which in my example is a geometric pattern based on the email hash.

Whilst this solution might not be as flexible as the package in your question, if all you're after is a gravatar and don't care whether it's isometric or a robot (see [default images](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) in the API docs for changing the default image generated) then something simple like this might be all you need.